# prism 6 or template 10 for windows 10?

Tags: xaml, prism, windows-10-universal, template10

which framework should a dotnet newcomer use/learn to build a scalable windows 10 applications [prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism) or [template10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10). I cant choose for myself because both assumes WPF experience. It's like learning xaml I have to go back to wpf docs just to supplement the windows 10 xaml docs which is not so helpful.

Comment: This was an excellent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template 10 is heavily based on Prism.  You can't go wrong with either one.  Both will achieve what you want.

Comment: So you're saying Template 10? Of course you are. :)

Comment: Is that what I'm saying?  I'm pretty sure it's obvious I was saying to use Prism :)